# update blob in java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

when i want to update a blob column in my table i this error

> Result Set not updatable.This result set must come from a statement
>   that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
>   the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must
>   select all primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API
>   Specification, section 5.6 for more details.This result set must come
>   from a statement that was created with a result set type of
>   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can
>   not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table.
>   See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.

but my statement is updatable !
can any body help me ?

this is my code that create statement

```
public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) {
    try {
        return con.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseAccessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is the way that i want to update blob

```
resultSet.updateBlob("mainPic", mainPic.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Show the code where you update the blob too, please.

Comment: i update my question . thanks

Comment: Show the code for the updateBlob() method

Answer (score -1):

this is my code :

```
DatabaseAccessor accessor = new DatabaseAccessor();
PreparedStatement statement = accessor.getPreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM  mainpage WHERE ID=0");
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
resultSet.next();

mainPic = request.getPart("mainPic");
resultSet.updateBlob("mainPic", mainPic.getInputStream());
```

Comment: this method is a method of ResultSet class